# Rails 3.1 Replacement for RXML Template Builder

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, view

What is the correct way of handling custom XML responses in Rails 3.1?

In Rails 2 I had the following action in my controller:

```
# GET the blog as a feed
def feed
  @blog = Blog.find(:first, :id => params[:id]])

  @blog_id = @blog.id
  @blog_posts = BlogPost.find(:all, :conditions => ["blog_id = ? AND is_complete = ?", @blog_id, true], :order => "blog_posts.created_at DESC", :limit => 15)
  render :action => :feed, :layout => false
end
```

And then a RXML builder template in the view, 'feed.rxml':

```
xml.instruct! :xml, :version=>"1.0"
xml.rss(:version=>"2.0") {
xml.channel {
    xml.title(@blog.title)  
    xml.link(url_for(:only_path => false))

    xml.description(@blog.subtitle)  
    xml.language('en-us')  
    for blog_post in @blog_posts
        xml.item do  
            xml.title(blog_post.title || '')  
            xml.link(blog_named_link(blog_post))
            xml.description(blog_post.body)  
            xml.tag(blog_post.tag_string)  
            xml.posted_by(blog_post.posted_by.name)  
        end  
     end  
    }
}
```

Rails 3.1 has eliminated the RXML template handler but I can't seem to find documentation on what we should replace it with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First add `respond_to` section to your action method

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.xml
end
```

or just add `respond_to :html, :xml` inside controller class definition

Then rename the template file to `feed.xml.builder`

Comment: I still get the following: Missing template blogs/feed, application/feed with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :prawn, :prawn_dsl, :haml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. And it is looking in the view folder that contains feed.xml.builder

Comment: @Andy oh, i should tell rails that i accept xml requests and generate xml files

Comment: Thanks, that got me on the right track. I inserted: request.format = "xml" unless params[:format] at the top of the 'feed' method since I only have that one method that should default to .xml format.

Comment: If your is only used for the xml output, you can add :format => "xml" to your route.

Answer (score 1):

ShiningRay's answer was almost 100% for me, but I had to also force it to not render the default layout in order to make the xml valid.

```
# force this to render as xml - this method *only* does xml
request.format = "xml" 
respond_to do |format|
  format.xml {render :layout => false} 
end
```